# How to surpass the login form guard detecting paste (Ctrl-V) operation and refuses to proceed

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium in order to automate login process into the website.

The website has two input fields: *username* and *password*. When I use selenium method **.sendkeys()** it successfully inserts data into the input fields.

**However**, after this (sendKeys operations) - website automatically adds characters - '_ad' into the *username* field so I've to manually remove those characters in order to login!

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
browser.get('url')

try:
  username_input = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username')))
  username_input.clear()
  username_input.send_keys("testt_ass")
except TimeoutException:
  print("Loading took too much time!")
```

If I type manually *username* from the very first character, website doesn't random characters. If I Ctrl-V - it does insert those into the *username*.
I assume that .sendkeys() doesn't involve any OS processes of typing and works just like Ctrl-V which leads to the aforementioned problem.

Could anyone please point me towards possible solution? Maybe there is a way to simulate read typing or any other way to surpass this guard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you modify the `value` attribute of the input field?

Comment: That's actually very interesting. When I manually set `value` inside devTools, then string **&shy;** is added at the same place where `ad` would be added. However, when I click on the value of the `value` inside devTools, I **can't see** that added `&shy`. What's the magic happening here.

Comment: But it's not really that helpful as it doesn't work. It requires actual input in the input element.